# My iOS App skips a method while running

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, methods

I am working on a project in which there are series of videos and in-between images for user interaction I have to display. At first it works fine but when I executed the app for second time it skips the user interaction. 
I'm currently working on this code:

```
-(void) playScene
{
if([scenetype isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]])
{
// plays a video using AVPlayer
...

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nextScene:)
                                                                         name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:Nil];
}

else
{
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];

                    imageView.frame = View.bounds;

                    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                    tapImage = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checkTouch:)];

                    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapImage];

                    [View addSubview:imageView];
}

}
```

In check touch method;

```
-(void)checkTouch: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:imageView];

if(location.x > 20.0 && location.x < 50.0)
{
//somedata
...

[self playScene];
}
else
{
...
[self playScene];
}
}
```

and finally in next scene:

```
-(void) nextScene: (NSNotification *) anotification
{

if(nextscene)
{
//somedata
...
[self playScene];
}

else
{
exit(0);
}
}
```

It shows the image when the if condition not true, but it skips the user interaction method, enters nextScene() method and video plays above the image. What I'm missing here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really get whay you're trying to achieve, but I can tell you that if you call multiple times to ``[self playScene]``, you will register your class as observer several times and that's going to fire ``nextScene:`` as many times as you have registered.

Comment: I'm trying to play a sequence of videos and in between some videos there will be images for interaction

Comment: I have also removed observer in 'nextScene:'